# Fluent nhibernate SQL Server 2008 R2 Express very long string saving issue

Tags: sql-server, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have an Article object which has various properties:

```
public class Article {
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Body { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the fluent configuration to load the mappings:

```
configuration.Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add((AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Article>())
                            .Conventions.Add(DefaultCascade.All())
                            .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<SchemaConfigurationController>())
```

The override is:

```
public class ArticleOverrideMapping : IAutoMappingOverride<Article>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Article> mapping)
    {
       //mapping.Map(x => x.Body).CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR(4000)");
       //mapping.Map(article => article.Body).Length(10000);
       //mapping.Map(article => article.Body).Length(Int32.MaxValue);            
       //mapping.Map(article => article.Body).CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR(max)");           
       //mapping.Map(article => article.Body).CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR(max)").Length(Int32.MaxValue);           
       mapping.Map(article => article.Body).CustomType("StringClob").CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR(max)");
    }
}
```

I have tried each of the commented out lines (roughly in order of when I found a possible solution online).  I can get SQL Server to create the `nvarchar(max)` column and if I use SQL management studio I can paste a LOT (185,602 words was largest test) into the Body column.  My issue is trying to get it to save from the MVC site using NHibernate.

There are two main errors I get:

> String or binary data would be truncated.  The statement has been terminated.

This would occur if I didn't set the `.Length(Int32.MaxValue)` override.

The second Error that occurs (when the length is set):

> The length of the string value exceeds the length configured in the mapping/parameter.

I am pretty confused as to what I should be doing at this point.  My goal is to be able to store a very large string (an whole article) in SQL Server (and SQLite for testing, nvarchar(max) wasn't liked by SQLite) and get that back out, (and edit it) in an MVC site.

**UPDATE**

As per @Cymen's link I tried

```
.CustomSqlType("nvarchar(max)").Length(Int32.MaxValue).Nullable();
```

but this lead to the error:

```
The length of the string value exceeds the length configured in the mapping/parameter.
```

when I only tried to save 1201 words (all the word "test").  When I added the length on the end of the above mapping ".Length(Int32.MaxValue)"  I still the same error.

**update**

wanted to confirm which versions I am using:

```
 FluentNHibernate.1.3.0.733
 NHibernate.3.3.1.4000
 Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0
```

**final update**

Kieren had it correct, I had completely forgotten that I took that property and ran markdownsharp on it on the server and populated a second property on the server.  So it was the second property that I hadn't mapped that was actually blowing up, sorry.

Comment: Could this be the solution?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708171/the-length-of-the-string-value-exceeds-the-length-configured-in-the-mapping-para Unfortunately, it doesn't say how to fix this when using fluent...

Comment: It looks like this should be a solution with fluent: http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2009/01/fluent-nhibernate-and-nvarcharmax.html

Comment: @Cymen thanks for the links, unfortunately I had already seen these two. updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: after each option you tried, what length/size column does it create in the database?

Comment: and, worth trying CustomSqlType("text")?  Crap compared to nvarchar(max) but it shouldn't be limited to a length

Comment: if I don't do any overrides it will create varchar(255), mapping.Map(x => x.Body).CustomSqlType("NVARCHAR(4000)") will create a nvarchar 4000.  The rest are (nvarchar(max), null)

Comment: Can you be sure it's that column that has the error, then?  Maybe a different field is too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how i normally handle it.

`mapping.Map(x => x.Problem).CustomType("varchar(MAX)");`

not sure what CustomSqlType is, but i've never used it, and this works.

Comment: unfortunately I still get "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated." using: mapping.Map(x => x.Body).CustomType("varchar(max)");

Answer (score 1):

Ok, folks. Same stuff, so i've did some tests.

**It seems that int.MaxValue cannot be used as LENGTH for fluent.** If you do that, the resulting create SQL will be nvarchar(255). So if nhibernate (fluent) still generates such a script, then he is awaiting 255 chars at max.

**If you hovewer use int.MaxValue / 2, then everything is ok. At least in the script.**
Only reasonable explanation: unicode string, so for a single char fluent automatically takes 2 bytes. SO internally fluent hibernate may do a multiplication by 2. And if we get above 2GB space, who knows what fluent will do...

**Please let me know if it works with data too.**

Comment: FluentNHibernate isn't really involved in this. There is also no multiplication involved. However, NHibernate internally knows that for Unicode strings up to max 4000 characters it should use `nvarchar($length)` and for strings up to 1073741823 characters, it should use `nvarchar(max)`. What then (unfortunately) happens is that if you ask for a longer string, it won't be able to use any of those two, so it will fall back to the default, i.e. `nvarchar(255)`.