# The length of the string value exceeds the length configured in the mapping/parameter

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

We are facing an exception while using Nhibernate 3.3.3.GA product version, which says

> "The length of the string value exceeds the length configured in the
>   mapping/parameter."

and this is happening after we have upgraded the Nhibernate version from 3.1.0.4000 to 3.3.3.GA version.

I am facing this problem, even after having the length on the column defined. following is the mapping info

```
<property name="OldValue" type="string">
    <column name ="OldValue" length="2147483647" not-null="false" />
</property>
```

and definitely the length of the string is not exceeding.

Any fix or workaround?

Comment: show your mapping code

Answer (score 3):

You probably would like to use nvarchar(max). The mapping could be:

```
<property name="OldValue" type="StringClob" not-null="false" />
```

See here more similar how to:

- [The length of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12711809/1679310) ...
- [NHibernate Mapping a string field as nvarchar(MAX)](http://geekswithblogs.net/lszk/archive/2011/07/11/nhibernatemapping-a-string-field-as-nvarcharmax-in-sql-server-using.aspx) ...