# FluenNnhibernate - Error dehydrating property value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have seen a lot of these errors on stack overflow, and followed the answers closely but I genuinly can't see the same issues in my code.

I get the following exception when trying to commit my changes:

```
{"Error dehydrating property value for MyModel.Field"}
```

With and inner exception of:

```
{"The length of the string value exceeds the length configured in the mapping/parameter."}
```

I have a mapping override for the model that looks like this:

```
 mapping.Map(x => x.Field).Length(10000);
```

And the column in the database is `nvarchar(MAX)`.

If I check the value of the field in notepad++ it says the length is 5355, and the stack trace is not fiving up any more information. :(

I really think I have covered all the angles, why am I still getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in regards to NHibernate's handling of `nvarchar(max)`.

I remember seeing this last year: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12711809/1517578

That SO answer has links to explanations and workarounds for Fluent NHibernate.